# Сокращение axios запросов

Tags: javascript, axios

Есть вот такой axios запрос

```
async GetUsers({ commit }) {
     await axios.get('/users')
     .then((resp) => {
         // Какие-то операции с данными 
     })
     .catch((err) => {
         // Операции с ошибкой 
     }
}
```

Хочу сделать такой же запрос но на другой путь, и по другому обрабатывать приходящие данные, можно ли как-то создать шаблон этого кода и просто прокидывать путь и исполняемый код в .then()?

Comment: "можно ли" --- можно........... и раз тут async/await, то никакие then тут не нужны уже

Comment: А можете пожалуйста, привести пример?

Comment: ....Пример чего?